# how to get the first two items in HashMap<String, Integer>?

Tags: java

I've been trying a way to get the first 2 objects
I've already tried using the transition to arrays,
And also used in iterator

And every time I crash

```
    String[] strArr = (String[])map.keySet().toArray();    //crash
    Integer[] integerArr = (Integer[])map.values().toArray();


    String string1 = strArr[0];
    int value1 = integerArr[0];


    String string2 = strArr[1];
    int value2 = integerArr[1];
```

Comment: Try using `map.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);` and `map.values().toArray(new Integer[0]);`. But you'd better use `entrySet` and iterate over the 2 first items. Also keep in mind that HashMap is not ordered, so there is no "2 first" objects, you'll get just 2 random objects.

Comment: You seem confused about Maps and ordering. A HashMap is a lookup table. Not a array

Comment: Sounds like you have an XY Problem. Please show the full code and what you're actually  trying to accomplish

Comment: If the order is important, you may need to change your `HashMap` to [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: Ops! My mistake. Forgot to type the "no" word in there. I'll delete that comment to prevent any further confusion. Thanks @Paul :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should realize there are no "first 2 objects" in a `HashMap`, since there is no ordering in a `HashMap`.

You can obtain arbitrary two entries that happen to be returned first when iterating over the `HashMap`:

```
String[] keys = new String[2];
Integer[] values = new Integer[2];
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < 2 && iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
    Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = iterator.next();
    keys[i] = entry.getKey();
    values[i] = entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no real concept of ordering in a HashMap. If you want insertion order, use a LinkedHashMap, and if you want lexicographic ordering, use a TreeMap. But anyway, here is how you would it.

```java
String[] keys = new String[2];
Integer[] ints = new Integer[2]; // int[] also works
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

for (int i = 0; i < 2 && it.hasNext(); i++) {
    Map.Entry<String,Integer> e = it.next();
    keys[i] = e.getKey();
    ints[i] = e.getValue();
}
```